# Use iOS 11 APIs whilst maintaining iOS 10 compatibility

Tags: ios

I'm working on updating my app to IOS 11, but I'm having some difficulties. I started using the new large titles with the code below:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

However, the compiler keeps complaining that `UINavigationbar` has no member `prefersLargeTitles` when I compile the app for iOS 10. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue (Xcode 9 beta 2). Which version of Xcode are you using? I believe you need Xcode 9 for this to work.

Comment: Palle is right. XCode 8 has no recollection of prefersLargeTitles.